In SmartTable , Table type is Tree Type, where after save operation all nodes are getting collapsed, need to save previous state after save operation
I have requirement where we have used Smart table of Table type "Tree". Here after save operation, all leaf nodes are getting collapsed. So after save operation it should show previous expanded view onscreen.
I have tried with Expand property, but it is not working as expected. Please can anyone help here me with suggestions,
So after save operation it should show previous expanded view onscreen.
